# calling transfer of ERC20 token using call function is not working

Tags: erc-20, eth-call

I tried to make token transfer contract like this,

```
contract TokenSender {
    function transferToken(address token1Address, address to, uint256 amount) external {
        (bool check, ) = token1Address.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("transfer(address,uint256)",to,amount));
        require(check, "tokenA is not transferred");
    }
}
```

But the check is always failed. but I change transfer to approve, then it is working. but both have same interface.

What I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to approve this contract address to be bale to manage your funds externally. You will need to do is using the token's approve function.

Comment: I miss understood about the call function. when contractA is calling to contractB, the msg.sender is contractA. I thought it is the owner.

and `delegate call` will also not work, because it supposed not to change B's storage. right?

Comment: I tried this way, first of all I tried to `approve` some amount and transaction was successful but when i check `allowance` from token contract, it returns me `0`.do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Call the approve function before transfer the function ,it will work , basically you need to approve the allowance everytime you make the transaction.